# How to auto-deploy web-app

Tags: php, deployment, automation

I'm trying to make sense on the best way to do automatize a series of things in a row in order to deploy a web-app and haven't yet came up with a suitable solution. I would like to:

1. use google's compiler.jar to minify my JS
2. use yahoo's yui-compressor.jar to minify my CSS
3. access a file and change a string so that header files like "global.css?v=21" get served the correct version
4. deploy the app (sftp, mercurial or rsync?) omitting certain directories like "/userfiles"

Can you guys put me on the right track to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a great application of Maven and ANT. Check those two tools out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you may want to check out phing http://phing.info/ (they are in the process of moving servers so may be down this weekend), but it can do all of what you are wanting and is written in php.
A quick google search should bring up plenty of tutorials to get you started.

Comment: I've been playing around with Phing and haven't yet made it do all the things I wished for but it does seam like the way to go. One thing I did find lacking was recursive SCP support.

I'll probably go with rSync: http://www.fedecarg.com/projects/show/filesynctask

Comment: Frankie you may want to look at the exec task or check the doc on writing a custom task.

Answer (score 2):

You can run php from the [command line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) to do all sorts of fun things.

```
$ php script_name.php arg1 arg2
```

See: [command line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), [argv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php), [argc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php), [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php)

Running PHP from the command line is very fast.  I've been doing this a lot lately for various automation tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I generally run Python projects so this may or may not be an option for you: but apart from writing your own scripts you could look into the following:

- [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/)
- [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/)
- [maven](http://maven.apache.org/)