# Best way to append changes to web application

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, vps

As your webapp goes more and more popular, you need something better than uploading new version of your code manually via FTP.

I decided to create a script that will automate it and perform the whole process as fast as possible. It looks like this:

1. Detect which files have changed and are going to be replaced by new versions of them.
2. Upload all the new files and these from step 1 to /temp/
3. Replace current .htaccess with "Deny from all"
4. Move all uploaded files from /temp/ to correct location
5. Perfrom all SQL queries that change anything in databases
6. Restore old .htaccess file
7. Delete all the files that are not in the new version of our app.
8. Delete /temp/

Is there anything else I can do to make update invisible to users?

I am using VPS with root access.

Comment: What you want is a *deployment process*, which has been discussed at length before; for example in [How to auto-deploy web-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754676/how-to-auto-deploy-web-app). Couple that with *migrations* to update what needs updating.

Comment: Have you looked into rsync?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. These tools do what I want but I also want to avoid situations when somebody requests a file that is currently being updated

Comment: A decent deployment tool like Capistrano will deploy into a separate directory and just update a symlink of the "current directory" when the process is completely done, so updates are atomic.

Comment: You need change to Cloud Computing first.